# Sum items in a join statement MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have three tables, a table for users, one for orders and the last one that contains the order items.

I've created a SQL query that gets all the orders and joins the user into the results, now I want to join the order items into the query. One order can have multiple order items. Each order item has a price. I need the sum of all the order_items that corresponds to the order_item.

So I will get a result that looks like this:
id, order_id, userid, order_time, id, name, email, price

Right now my query looks this:

```
SELECT huxwz_user_orders.*, huxwz_users.name, huxwz_users.email, huxwz_users.id, SUM(huxwz_user_orderitems.price)
FROM huxwz_user_orders
LEFT OUTER JOIN huxwz_users ON (
    huxwz_user_orders.userid = huxwz_users.id
)
LEFT OUTER JOIN huxwz_user_orderitems ON (
    huxwz_user_orders.id = huxwz_user_orderitems.orderid
)
```

thing is, the SUM is doing a sum of all the order item, which means that i only get one result :/

Any ideas on how I could fix this?

Comment: you need to have `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: Can you show me, I'm a little confused as to where to place it :<?

Comment: Here is the documentation about using Group By: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html

Comment: can you give sample records with your desired result? Having `SELECT *` in the query with `GROUP BY` clause not specifying all non aggregated columns is a bad habit, though it works in mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT huxwz_user_orders.*, huxwz_users.name, huxwz_users.email, huxwz_users.id, SUM(huxwz_user_orderitems.price)
FROM huxwz_user_orders
LEFT OUTER JOIN huxwz_users ON (
    huxwz_user_orders.userid = huxwz_users.id
)
LEFT OUTER JOIN huxwz_user_orderitems ON (
    huxwz_user_orders.id = huxwz_user_orderitems.orderid
)
Group BY huxwz_user_orderitems.orderid
ORDER BY huxwz_user_orders.id
```

I did this, and it seems perfectly as I wanted it to, thanks for the grouping info, it works! :3

Comment: If others haven't answered your question, but you have - you can accept this answer.  Otherwise advisable to make this an update to your question and accept the answer that helped most.

Comment: Hi Orbling, I wanted to make it the answer, but stackoverflow says I have to wait two days :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using oracle?

If so, this might be what you want:

```
SUM(huxwz_user_orderitems.price) OVER (PARTITION BY huxwz_user_orderitems.orderid)
```

If not, I guess you'll have to make a select of all your order items, a select with all totals per order (group by having) and join those 2 result sets.

```
SELECT a.*, b.total
FROM
(SELECT huxwz_user_orders.*, huxwz_users.name, huxwz_users.email, huxwz_users.id
FROM huxwz_user_orders
LEFT OUTER JOIN huxwz_users ON (
    huxwz_user_orders.userid = huxwz_users.id
)
LEFT OUTER JOIN huxwz_user_orderitems ON (
    huxwz_user_orders.id = huxwz_user_orderitems.orderid
)
) a,
(
SELECT o.id, SUM(oi.price) total
FROM huxwz_user_orders o,
JOIN huxwz_user_orderitems oi ON o.id = oi.orderid
GROUP BY o.id
) b
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to remove asterisk from your select and then put GROUP BY like this:

```
SELECT huxwz_user_orders.field1, huxwz_users.name, huxwz_users.email, huxwz_users.id, 
SUM(huxwz_user_orderitems.price)
FROM huxwz_user_orders
LEFT OUTER JOIN huxwz_users ON (
    huxwz_user_orders.userid = huxwz_users.id
)
LEFT OUTER JOIN huxwz_user_orderitems ON (
    huxwz_user_orders.id = huxwz_user_orderitems.orderid
)
GROUP BY huxwz_user_orders.field1, huxwz_users.name, huxwz_users.email, huxwz_users.id
```

or maybe it will be easier for you to use nested query:

```
SELECT huxwz_user_orders.field1, huxwz_users.name, huxwz_users.email, huxwz_users.id, 
(SELECT SUM(price) FROM huxwz_user_orderitems WHERE huxwz_user_orders.id = orderid) AS  price
FROM huxwz_user_orders
LEFT OUTER JOIN huxwz_users ON (
    huxwz_user_orders.userid = huxwz_users.id
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT huxwz_user_orders.*, huxwz_users.name, huxwz_users.email, huxwz_users.id, SUM(huxwz_user_orderitems.price)
FROM huxwz_user_orders
LEFT OUTER JOIN huxwz_users ON (
    huxwz_user_orders.userid = huxwz_users.id
)
LEFT OUTER JOIN huxwz_user_orderitems ON (
    huxwz_user_orders.id = huxwz_user_orderitems.orderid
)GROUP BY
huxwz_users.name, huxwz_users.email, huxwz_users.id
```